# The below code, a json file has some missing errors but no visible corrections are displayed. Appreciate any help or suggestions

Tags: mysql, json, flutter, dart, phpmyadmin

`Future<List> senddata() async {`
``` }    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(("``http://localhost/app/insertdata.php``"), body: { ```
`)      "name": user.text`
`"email": pass.text`
`"mobile":mobile.text`
`});`

`var datauser = json.decode(response.body);`

connection file to a database, have but does not display any errors

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure your device is connected to internet
- You need to establish connection to the SQL first before requesting any thing in your localhost
- Your application and localhost server should be running on the same port to use API's locally in your application.

Comment: There is already a connection file and another for inserting data when the application is in action. It merely displayed undefined name even though the relative classes were created

Comment: can you share minimum reproducable code. I meant to say all the related code to this function.

Comment: Unfortunately this is all there is regarding this function

Comment: Usually, you need to make API first for this type of method with defined API function types. And the application and localhost should be running on the same port at. the same time.

Comment: Thanks a lot. appreciate the suggestions